# How to authenticate box.net programmatically?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, box-api

I am using OAuth 2.0 protocol to authenticate. I am not getting any way to obtain access token programmatically without any user interaction(no UI at all). The purpose is to list all files of all users under enterprise Box.Net account. The flow I am expecting is like [service account](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount) of google Drive.

Comment: You can't automate ( i.e. skip the human authorization interfaction)when using OAuth 2.0

Comment: Do I have any alternative for OAuth 2.0 to achieve this?

Comment: An alternative that all of those services support, that doesn't exist.

Comment: So, I hereby conclude that, as of now it is not possible to get a list of files without User's presence(with no human interaction). Am I right?

Comment: This was in a relateed question "Box's implementation of OAuth2 does not generate permanent tokens." this means that even if you had a valid security token Box.net doesn't support it.  Other services do support permanent tokens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible with Box's current implementation of OAuth 2, though we're working on supporting additional grant types.

Comment: Eight months later - has the process of "working on additional grant types been completed yet?

Comment: @seanrose: Have your work completed for Cosole/Library supports. I mean authenticate without user interaction?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using only one box enterprise account then you can always create your access token and refresh token just once using browser and then programmatically refresh your access token before 14 days using cron on server side.

Comment: Sensible!!! I also thought on similar lines and implemented it. I wish we will have something like Google service accounts in near future. Thanks for your answer.